# MATLAB examples are failing

Tags: matlab

I don't have the slightest idea what's going on here, and Google provides no interesting help. I took the following example from http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/solve.html#inputarg_eqn

```
>> syms x
>> solve(x^2 + 4*x + 1 == 0)
??? Error using ==> char
Conversion to char from logical is not possible.

Error in ==> solve>getEqns at 169
   vc = char(v);

Error in ==> solve at 67
[eqns,vars] = getEqns(varargin{:});
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The documentation you're reading doesn't apply to your version of MatLab.  I can reproduce your error in 2008b, for example.

The older documentation says:

> Note that these examples assume equations of the form `f(x)  =  0`. If you need to solve equations of the form `f(x)  =  q(x)`, you must use quoted strings. In particular, the command
>
> ```
> s = solve('cos(2*x)+sin(x)=1')
> ```

In the future, pay attention to the line at the top of every MatLab online documentation page where it says what version the documentation applies to.